# Preventing submit form in case of inline attached events

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, preventdefault

How would I override a submit events attached inline to my form to be more precise I have the following form

```
<form id="myForm">
   //some fields
   <a onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit()" ></a>
</form>
```

my javascript parses all forms on current page and searches for input fields named email. If finds such fields should prevent submit and execute some validation. Some of the forms on pages have already events attached as the form bellow shows but I don't know how to prevent submit in this case

so my actual javascript here https://jsfiddle.net/g0rf2r99/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution that attempts to solve this scenario:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    alert("Input value:" + " " + form.elements.myValue.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<form action="example/submit.html">
    Value: <input type="text" name="myValue">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Notice how the form has a text input named myValue and a submit button titled Save.

In the JavaScript, you'd see that an event listener is added to the form element to listen on the submit event. Within that event handler an alert is displayed with the user input. The default behaviour of submit is then stalled using event.preventDefault().

In your code, you would identify the email field, execute the validation and prevent the default submit behaviour in place of the call to alert in the example.